# Magento error with custom module

Tags: magento

I am getting the following error when I tried to create a Magento custom module.

I have followed this tutorial but can't see where I am going wrong, can anyone help please?

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

```
2015-03-23T23:57:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage\Company\ScheduledPriceDrop\Model\Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\Work\@Company\Project1\src\trunk\public_html\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94
2015-03-23T23:57:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage\Company\ScheduledPriceDrop\Model\Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\Work\@Company\Project1\src\trunk\public_html\app\code\local;C:\Work\@Company\Project1\src\trunk\public_html\app\code\community;C:\Work\@Company\Project1\src\trunk\public_html\app\code\core;C:\Work\@Company\Project1\src\trunk\public_html\lib;.;C:\php\pear')  in C:\Work\@Company\Project1\src\trunk\public_html\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94
2015-03-23T23:57:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage\Company\ScheduledPriceDrop\Model\Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\Work\@Company\Project1\src\trunk\public_html\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94
2015-03-23T23:57:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage\Company\ScheduledPriceDrop\Model\Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\Work\@Company\Project1\src\trunk\public_html\app\code\local;C:\Work\@Company\Project1\src\trunk\public_html\app\code\community;C:\Work\@Company\Project1\src\trunk\public_html\app\code\core;C:\Work\@Company\Project1\src\trunk\public_html\lib;.;C:\php\pear')  in C:\Work\@Company\Project1\src\trunk\public_html\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94
2015-03-23T23:57:01+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Object of class Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule could not be converted to string  in C:\Work\@Company\Project1\src\trunk\public_html\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 2869
```

Comment: Can you post all of the file contents so I can check please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your log the execution didn't find the **observer.php** in your module

> Company\ScheduledPriceDrop\Model\Observer.php

Actually it seems that it is searching for this observer file in core, this mostly happens if it doesnot find it in local domain.

If this is not the case than you have to provide your code.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

There is error in this module Company\ScheduledPriceDrop disable it. there is error in this module you need to correct it.